# Calculated Field (IIF)

Tags: ms-access, calculated-field, iif

Okay, well I'm currently designing a database for my university coursework. I am struggling on a calculated field within a query. The calculated field is made up of an IIF expression via the expression builder. The main problem is, the calculated field works, however, as I have put "Not Applicable" within the false part of the IIF, it still comes up as #Error? Here below is my IIF!

```
IIf([Quantity]=20,[Total After Discount]*0.95,
    IIf([Quantity]=50,[Total After Discount]*0.925,
        IIf([Quantity]=100,[Total After Discount]*0.9,
            IIf([Quantity]>=200,[Total After Discount]*0.875,"Not Applicable."))))
```

Any help/ideas or suggestions please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This query calculates the total AFTER discount. Therefore its input should be the total BEFORE discount. You are probably doing something like this:

```
SELECT IIf([Quantity]=20,[Total After Discount]*0.95,...) AS [Total After Discount]
FROM ...
```

So in this expression `[Total After Discount]` is referring to itself, which is not possible. Change it to

```
SELECT IIf([Quantity]=20,[Total Before Discount]*0.95,...) AS [Total After Discount]
FROM ...
```

If `[Total After Discount]` is a column in another query or table and you want to use the same column name in the result again, you can do it by qualifying the column name by the table or query name:

```
SELECT
    IIf([Quantity]=20, MyTable.[Total After Discount]*0.95, ...)
        AS [Total After Discount]
FROM MyTable
```

This eliminates the unallowed recursion.

---

But is your logic really correct? Shouldn't it be:

```
IIf([Quantity]>=200,[Total Before Discount]*0.875,
    IIf([Quantity]>=100,[Total Before Discount]*0.9,
        IIf([Quantity]>=50,[Total Before Discount]*0.925,
            IIf([Quantity]>=20,[Total Before Discount]*0.95,[Total Before Discount]))))
```

Turn the logic around. You are not showing the disount, but the total after discount, so you should display the total instead of "Not Applicable".

If you were showing the discount then yes, display "Not Applicable":

```
IIf([Quantity]>=200,"12.5%",
    IIf([Quantity]>=100,"10%",
        IIf([Quantity]>=50,"7.5%",
            IIf([Quantity]>=20,"5%","Not Applicable")))) As DiscountPercent
```

Comment: Ah ! Okay, well i've just used your last expression just showing the discount, and it works! 

HOWEVER, 

How would I make it multiply? As you can't really multiple a field with "Not Applicable"?

Comment: BTW, the company is meant to buy books from the publisher at a discuonted rate hence why i have total after discount. 

HOWEVER

I've been asked to add in a discount on top in relation to the order size. 

Hope that has helped your understanding of my database

Comment: Okay, I've used your logic, and added two fields, so one showing the discount, and one showing the total after all discounts! 

You my friend, are a LEGEND!

Comment: If you have to do a multiplication put it inside the IIF: Like `IIf([Quantity]>=200,Quantity*Price*0.875, ...)` instead of before or after the IIF: `Quantity*IIf([Quantity]>=200,Price*0.875, ...)`, so you will never be multiplying with a text.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that you can mix number/text answers in a calculated field. You'd be better served to use a query in this case and not a calculated field. I've avoided using calculated fields thus far do to their limitations (such as this).

Comment: Hi, yes I am using a query however, I need to work out discounts in relation to order size... e.g If the order is 20, then I need a discount of 5% etc... so what is the best way to do this?